# data structure python django

Tags: python, django, data-structures

I am working on my first Django project and I am strugling to define my data structure in my view that I will push to my template.

I want to define the following, writing in example pseudo code to give you an idea:

To be written in view:

```
games[0].time = '12:00'
games[0].hometeam = 'Manchester United'
games[0].awayteam = 'Chelsea'

games[1].time = '15:00'
games[1].hometeam = 'Manchester United'
games[1].awayteam = 'Chelsea'
```

Subsequenly I want to use this data in my template by adding the following to my template file:

```
<td class="RowData">{{games[0].time}}</td>
```

etc.

I want to use a structured  approach in stead of a normal list to keep the overview in my template file.

I currently get an error stating: `global name 'games' is not defined`

I assume  that I need to create a 'games' object as instantiation of a new to be defined class, correct?, or would there be a better solution to structure my data before sending it to my template?

I will subsequently complete the 'games' date structure with a for loop using data from a queryset like:

```
for x in range(0,queryset.count()):
    games[x].time = [str(queryset[x].gametimedate.hour)+':'+str(queryset[x].gametimedate.minute)
    games[x].hometeam = queryset[x].hometeam                 
    games[x].queryset[x].awayteam
```

Help to explaining docs or example is appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

you could keep games as a list but use dictionaries for each element inside your the list, this will allow you to keep the key/value structure for each game:

```
games = []
games.append({'time':'12:00', 'hometeam': 'Manchester United', 'awayteam': 'Chelsea'})
games.append({'time':'15:00', 'hometeam': 'Manchester United', 'awayteam': 'Chelsea'})
```

and will also let you loop through the list and/or refer to a game by its index.

So for example using dot notation in a django template to access the first game's time would look like this:

```
{{games.0.time}}
```

Here is more about dictionaries in the python documentation: https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries

And here is bit in Django documentation that explains dot notation in templates https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/api/#variables-and-lookups